# Bootstrap (Angular), Main Content not occupying full height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Okay, I know that this question might have been asked by different users under different circumstances, but I am really stuck here and I have tried most of the suggestions. The problem is I cannot get the content to occupy full space. There is always a small gap and this worsens with decrease in screen resolution (1920*1080, 1366*766, 1024*768) etc. The gap between the footer and the main content keeps on getting bigger when the resolution decreases.

I will attach all the images down below. I am using angular bootstrap and this is my code structure

```
    <body>
      <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        .....
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:0px;">
       <!-- Inspite of adding row padding was not getting negated -->
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">Angular UI Carousel Code Here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Login Form Code Here</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
       <div class="container-fluid">
        .....
       </div> 
     </footer>
    </body>
```

CSS Used (Along with bootstrap css - angular variant)

```
html {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

body {
    padding-top: 75px;
    color: #34495e;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #54A275;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Body has a `padding-top:75px` to accomodate the header which is 75px high

1920 * 1080
[image: The gap between the batman pic and the footer is little]
1366 * 768
[image: The gap starts to increase]
1024*768
[image: The gap is huge]

How do I make sure that the full screen real estate is utilized?

Comment: Please share your CSS used here.

Comment: Added the basic styles

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following styles to the <div> next to the <header> tag:

</header>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="ADD STYLES HERE">


padding-left: 0px;
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding-top: 75px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
```

Comment: Because of bottom:0 the header occupies, almost 100% of the page height

Comment: Yes. It will cover whole page( height: 100% and width: 100%). As we have header and footer so the content should have padding-top and padding-bottom to adjust its content. Remember we have always fixed height "header" and "footer". In your case header have 75px and footer have 40px height, so padding-top: 75px and padding-bottom: 40px. Remove padding-top from the body.

Answer (score -1):

is there a url where we can see the page? I see different aspect ratios here.
1024x768 is 4:3, the other two are 16:9 (1366*768 is almost 16:9). Your image may be in 16:9 ratio, so when you change your resolution to 4:3 and since the image is getting re-sized proportionally, there can be spaces or gaps.

Comment: Sorry, no url. Okay, I think a simple version of my question would, how do I make sure that whatever content I put, occupies full height available to it?

Comment: You are right I suppose, because I resized the photo to fix the exact dimensions and sure enough it worked. Isn't there any way to make the image stretch / fit the boundary?

Comment: you cannot till you scale your image proportionally.  You will have to stretch your image vertically and that would distort the image. Get the height if the container div and use that to change to height of the image.